# How to void that a button being active while send data to a database using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that sends data to a database and I would like to void that the user press the send button again while data is beeing saved in the database.

Hier my code that works, but without this functionality:

```
    $(function(){
        var $loading = $('.spinner').hide();
        $(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {$loading.show();})
            .ajaxStop(function () {$loading.hide();});

        $('form.publn-nr-srch').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/publicationSearch/pubSearchScr.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('form.publn-nr-srch').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    $('div.result').html(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Then I tried among others this one:

```
    $(function(){
        var $loading = $('.spinner').hide();
        var $button = $('.send-data').enable();
        $(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                $button.disable();
                $loading.show();
            })
            .ajaxStop(function () {
                $button.disable();
                $loading.hide();
            });

        $('form.publn-nr-srch').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/publicationSearch/pubSearchScr.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('form.publn-nr-srch').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    $('div.result').html(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

But everything I've done hasn't worked.
I would appreciate with you could help me.

**EDIT**

Here is the code based on the answer of @ahmed.hoban:

```
        $('form.publn-nr-srch').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({

                beforeSend: function(){
                    $button.prop("disabled",true);
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $button.prop("disabled",false);
                },

                url: '/publicationSearch/pubSearchScr.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('form.publn-nr-srch').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    $('div.result').html(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Is it right?

Comment: You can make the button disable for a moment . When Ajax starts, disable the button and reactivate it when ajax completes its operation

Comment: I use this great plugin for deactivate buttons http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/ for bootstrap

Comment: Hello @RahulVarma, thanks for your answer. Could you please show me how can I do it with an example in my code?

Comment: I have added the answer ! Do Check it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this work!

```
$('form.publn-nr-srch').submit(function(){
       $('button').prop("disabled",true);
            $.ajax({

                url: '/publicationSearch/pubSearchScr.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('form.publn-nr-srch').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    $('button').prop("disabled",false);
                    $('div.result').html(response);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

try it with beforeSend and set the 'prop' to disabled (jquery way)

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function(){
    $button.prop("disabled",true);
  },
  complete: function() {
    $button.prop("disabled",false);
  }

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks @ahmed.hoban for your answer!
I edited my code. Is this the correct way to insert your code in mine?
I'm having problem with that too...

Comment: what is the problem? Make sure $button is referencing the button correctly and this should definitely disable the button after click and enable it if its complete.